# Magento2 emojone script included in magento

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.6

In my Magento2 - I noticed that it is downloading a script `emojione.min.js` from https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/emojione/2.2.7/lib/js/emojione.min.js.

is it a default magento script?
I also tried to find out how it is included, but couldn't find any reference to this JS file either in my filesystem or database.
So I think the same is being included by some malware.

I need some help to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

This script is not from default Magento. May be this is malware.

To find this script go to Admin->Content->Design->Configuration

Then edit each store and check Scripts and Style sheets from HTML Head and Miscellaneous HTML from Footer section.

Remove the script from this section if you found the same ans save. Clear the cache and check.

Hope it will work for you.